# Choosing A Group With Conditions

Tags: combinatorics

A Man hold a party and invites 5 out of 8, of his friends.
1) what are the numbers of possibilities if 2 friends has a fight and they do not agree to come both
2) what are the numbers of possibilities if 2 friends will come only if 2 other are arriving.

1) we will choose all the combinations and reduce those when we know that the 2 friends that fought have been chosen.

${8\choose 5}-{6\choose3}$

2) we have 2 options a. when the 2 are coming for sure b. when the 2 are not coming therefore only 1 of the (needed) friend is chosen

option a.is 
 $6\choose3$ option b is $6\choose5$ so it is ${6\choose3}+{6\choose5}$

I am not sure about the answer ecpesially 2

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your solution for question 1).
I agree with option a for question 2). 
Option a is conditioning on the fact that BOTH the "2 are coming for sure".
But if NOT BOTH of them are coming there are only two ways to invite a total of five friends.  Your (6 choose 5) is double counting.
I think the correct answer for question 2) is (6 choose 3) + 2 = 22.

Comment: The answer for 2. is 26

Comment: Lets say the 8 people are {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}. 1 and 2 are the people that refuse to come to the party unless 7 and 8 are both at the party.  I think we agree that there are (6 choose 3) ways if both 7 and 8 are invited.  If not both 7 and 8 are invited then the only ways are to invite {3,4,5,6,7} and {3,4,5,6,8}.

Comment: but if both 7 and 8 are coming so 1 and 2 may come too

Comment: Yes, and we counted these ways in the first case: If both 7 and 8 are invited.  We agreed that there are 6 choose 3 ways.  If 7 and 8 are not invited there are only two ways.  I claim the correct answer is 22.